# call a generic method with an object of an unknown type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have this method

```
public string DictionaryToString<T, U>(Dictionary<T, U> dict)
{
  var valueStrings = dict.Select(x => x.Key.ToString() + ": " + x.Value.ToString());
  return String.Join("\n", valueStrings);
}
```

And I have this object that I want to pass into it

```
if ((value !=null) && value.GetType().IsGenericType &&
  value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Dictionary<,>))
{
   var castValue = value as Dictionary<,>; // this cast does not work
   return DictionaryToString(castValue);
}
else
{
  return value.ToString();
}
```

I can use reflection code like this in .Net 4.5

```
var targetMethodInfo = typeof(MyType).GetMethod("DictionaryToString");
var valueTypeArgs = value.GetType().GenericTypeArguments;
var genericMethod = targetMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(valueTypeArgs);
var result = genericMethod.Invoke(this, new[] {value });
return result.ToString();
```

But`Type.GenericTypeArguments` is new in .Net 4.5. So how can I do that cast in .Net 4.0?

Comment: Why do you need to cast it? The check you have confirms that `castValue` is of type `Dictionary<,>` so shouldn't you just be able to pass it straight into your generic method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only calling `ToString` on the key and value, so simply have this method take an `IDictionary` (non-generic), you are not using anything in there that is type-specific to `T` or `U`.

You can then simply cast all arguments to `IDictionary`:

```
var d = arg as IDictionary;

if (d != null)
{
    var res = DictionaryToString(d);
}
```

You may also need to amend the `DictionaryToString` implementation:

```
static string DictionaryToString(IDictionary d)
{
    var vals = new List<string>();

    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in d)
    {
        vals.Add(de.Key.ToString() + ": " + de.Value.ToString());
    }

    return String.Join("\n", vals);
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use LINQ, you could try casting to `dynamic` (it isn't possible to cast to anything else as this could be a generic dictionary (`KeyValuePair<>`) or non-generic hashtable (`DictionaryEntry`)):

```
var valueStrings = d.Cast<dynamic>().Select(de => de.Key.ToString() + ": " + de.Value.ToString());
return string.Join("\n", valueStrings);
```

This basically "duck types" the existence of the `Key` and `Value` properties.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be a case for the old `System.Collections` namespace:

```
    private static string DictionaryToString(IDictionary dict) {
        if (null == dict) throw new ArgumentNullException("dict");

        var valueStrings = new List<string>();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in dict) {
            valueStrings.Add(item.Key + ": " + item.Value);
        }
        return string.Join("\n", valueStrings.ToArray());
    } 

    private static string Test(object value) {

        var dict = value as IDictionary;
        if (dict != null) {
            return DictionaryToString(dict);
        }

        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args) {

        var aDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> {
            { 1, "one" },
            { 2, "two" },
            { 3, "three" }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(Test(aDictionary));

        var anotherDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { "one", 1 },
            { "two", "2" },
            { "three", new object() }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(Test(anotherDictionary));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**Reasoning:**

The non-generic `IDictionary` will be a collection of key-value pairs in which the key is an `object` and the value is an `object`. All instances of `object` support `ToString`, so all keys and values of the collection can be converted to a `string` without knowing their specific types.

The reason why this does not work:

```
var castValue = value as Dictionary<,>
```

is because the generic type `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` requires 2 type arguments. Without those type arguments, the collection is not generic. You'd be better off using the non-generic `IDictionary` if you do not know the key or value types at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

GetGenericTypeDefinition is available for previous versions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.100).aspx. I think the 4.5 page on MSDN is missing the "Other versions" dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
if ((value !=null) && value.GetType().IsGenericType &&
       value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Dictionary<,>))
{
   return DictionaryToString(castValue);
}
else
{
  return value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast to `dynamic` in .NET 4.0. The prior `typeof(Dictionary<,>)` check will ensure that you won't get runtime errors.

```
var castValue = value as dynamic;
return DictionaryToString(castValue);
```